# Is there a difference between setting a variable to None or deleting it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a noticeable difference in performance or memory if you clear  variables by setting

```
x = 'something'
x = None
```

as opposed to

```
x = 'something'
del x
```

for many variables?

Comment: There is no difference in memory. Performance you can check yourself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both times the memory for `'something'` will be reclaimed *if* `x` was the last reference to that string object. In the first example, you use a tiny bit more memory because you keep the name `x` around.

I did some searching and it looks like the memory will be reclaimed immediately: [further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969739/python-del-statement).

There is a *conceptual difference*, however, and your program will behave differently. When you `del x`, you **unbind** the name `x`, and trying to use that name will raise a `NameError`:

```
>>> x = 'something'
>>> del x
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

When you set `x = None` you **rebind** `x` to be a name for the object `None`, and can still use the variable as expected. For example for truthy/falsy tests:

```
>>> x = None
>>> if not x:
...     print('hello cshin9!')
... 
hello cshin9!
```

Answer (score 6):

Setting a variable to None or deleting it both causes the reference to the object `x` to be released. The main difference is that with `x = None` the name `x` still exists, even though it's now pointing to a different object (`None`). When using `del` the name is deleted as well.

For the garbage collector, there is no difference. `del` does not force any garbage collection of the referenced object.

Edit: as @Viroide pointed out, using `del` causes an exception to be thrown when trying to call the variable `x`.

Comment: What would force garbage collection of the object?

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html `gc.collect()` will force the garbage collector to release unreferenced memory. I do not know of a method to explicitly release a single variable and I doubt such a method exists.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not the same, look at the following example:

```
x = "something"
x = None
type(x)
<type 'NoneType'>

z = "asd"
del z
type(z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'z' is not defined
```

Setting to None makes the variable value be None and have NoneType. But deleting the variable makes the variable inaccessible by deleting from the context.

Answer (score 2):

I was curious, so I decided to have a look at what the module [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) says by running this code:

```
import dis

def f():
    v = 'x' 
    v = None
    del v 
    return None

print(dis.dis(f))
```

The result is

```
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('x')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (v)

  5           6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (v)

  6          12 DELETE_FAST              0 (v)

  7          15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

and the documentations says that [DELETE_FAST](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-DELETE_FAST)

> Deletes local `co_varnames[var_num]`.

while [LOAD_CONST](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_CONST)

> Pushes `co_consts[consti]` onto the stack.

So, in terms of operations/memory, `LOAD_CONST` performs two operations (where one is using memory), and I think that it becomes relevant only when you have a high amount of elements (not just one) - therefore you might want to use `del`.

This also explains why you cannot access the variable `v` anymore (as it was deleted from the namespace, while `LOAD_CONST` is just another assignment).

Answer (score 1):

The two statements differ in a way they operate on the current namespace: the former simply changes the value of the variable, while `del` completely removes the variable. The previous value pointed by `x` gets garbage collected in any case.

Performance differences, if any, are negligible.